# How do I print out 100 numbers in an array then add them using C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to print out 100 numbers from an array using a loop and then add them all together. So far I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int* number = malloc(101 * sizeof(int));
    int num = 0;
    number[num] = 1;

    while (number[num] <= 100){
        printf(" %d\n ", number[num]);
        num = num +1;
        number[num] = number[num]+1;



    }

    return 0;
}
```

but this just prints 1 once.

Comment: Basically there is no array in your code.

Comment: And what is the problem you have with the code you show?

Comment: What's the behavior of this, according to you, "number[num] = number[num]+1;"  ?

Comment: Not to mention referencing the uninitialized value will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: I fixed it. edit: nvm idk how to add code to comments. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

   int n[ 100 ]; /* n is an array of 100 integers */
   int i,j;
   int sum = 0;

   /* initialization */
   for ( i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
      n[ i ] = i + 100;   /* set element at location i to i + 100 */
   }

   /* output each array element's value */
   for (j = 0; j < 100; j++ ) {
      printf("Element[%d] = %d\n", j, n[j]);
      sum += n[j];
   }

   printf("Sum of Elements = %d\n", sum);
   return 0;
}
```

Remember that you should declare an `array`, then initialize it, print it out and after all print out the `sum`

Comment: What do you mean by undefined behavior. I explain in comment that this part of code initialize array's location i to `i + 100`. So `n[0] = 100, n[1] = 101` and so on ... @chrisw69

Comment: I think I was mistaken, I thought `n[ i ] = i + 100` was undefined behavior, but not sure it is now. My C is rather rusty

Answer (score 1):

```
    number[num] = number[num]+1;
```

You only properly set `number[0]`. Now you are trying to take whats in `number[1]` and add to it, in the first iteration. You didn't set it to anything though, leaving it uninitialised. This is undefined behaviour. What you most likely wanted to do is

```
    number[num] = number[num-1]+1;
```

To add one to the previous number before after printing it. Now it will print fine.

To add them up, simply do

```
for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++) {
 number[100] += number[a]; // add number[a] to result
}
printf("%d\n",number[100]);
```

Also, don't forget to `free` your dynamically allocated array at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can just print out 1 to 100, then you could quickly use some maths to get the count of all numbers added together, for example, one of Gauss' algorithms, specifically http://betterexplained.com/articles/techniques-for-adding-the-numbers-1-to-100/

> There’s a popular story that Gauss, mathematician extraordinaire, had a lazy teacher. The so-called educator wanted to keep the kids busy so he could take a nap; he asked the class to add the numbers 1 to 100.

Here's what I would do: -

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  printf("%d", i);
}

// gauss technique 100(100 + 1) / 2

int count = (100 * 100 + 100 * 1) / 2;
printf("all numbers added: %d", count);
```